# AWS DynomoDB Access tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-parameter-store

I'm trying to create a backend(spring boot maven) API. After some couple failed attempts I got it to work with pipeline and all but received a notification that I "Leaked" my secret and access key to Github. I then tried to fix this by following the steps they sent me but now I can't get the backend to build and run

first I followed a tutorial to use AWS Parameter Store. This solution "Worked" for a while until I made new access keys because I read I shouldn't use my root user for these types of tasks and I need to create a new IAM user with the correct roles. I received new access and secret keys and updated my Parameter store accordingly. But now when the pipeline builds I get an error :

```
The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AWSSimpleSystemsManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: 43c12a04-e9cb-47e6-a0d7-4acec5e72c10; Proxy: null)
```

I fiddled quite a lot, changing things and pushing it to GitHub but nothing worked. I decided to stop pushing and just work on my local host. I stopped using the AWS Parameter store and just use the access and secret key as plain text and that worked on my localhost. So step by step I changed it back to using the parameter store and again the same error. I then read something about a file /C:/user...../.aws/credentials and saw that these values are still my old access and secret keys so I changed these and it worked!. everything works and I can request data from dynamo DB.

But when I went to upload it to Github and run the pipeline I get the same error. Is it possible that there is a file like the /C:/user...../.aws/credentials file in my code build that needs to be updated or many something else that I'm doing wrong?

any help would be appreciated!
let me how if you need some specific information that could help you help me.

Comment: How do you host your application (i.e. EC2, Elastic Beanstalk, etc)?

Comment: I host it on Beanstalk @stdunbar

Answer (score 0):

I would start with [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html) to setup your beanstalk environment such that you don't include your credentials in your code.

Ultimately, just like an EC2 your instances have credentials tied to them that your code will automatically get from the instance.  Your code may have to change slightly if your current credentials come from a profile besides the default one.  That is, if your `.aws/credentials` file looks like:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=THEACCESSKEY
aws_secret_access_key=THESECRETKEY

[some-profile]
aws_access_key_id=ADIFFERENTACCESSKEY
aws_secret_access_key=ADIFFERENTSECRETKEY
```

and you use code like:

```
AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create("some-profile);
```

you would either need to change that to the default profile or handle getting the credentials a different way - you'll try with the credentials provider and if that fails, use `DefaultCredentialsProvider`.  You can also specify the profile name when building the `DefaultCredentialsProvider` (SDK v2)

You can have one user that is your local development user and another that is your beanstalk user.  The would have similar or the same permissions but the credentials are stored separately.